# Why is leetcode changing my negative number to 6 when I submit my answer?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to submit the answer for "98. Validate Binary Search Tree" on Leetcode. When I test the result of my solution using the "Run Code" button with the binary tree represented by [0] as input, everything works as intended. However, when I click "Submit", if the number I declare as a public static int is a negative number (which it must be for the solution to work) it becomes 6 according to the stdout for the submission, and the test case gets a different result even though the program that is being used should be exactly the same (as far as I know). Is there some problem with Leetcode or am I just missing something? [Image that shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Igo.png)

Here is the code for my complete solution:

```
class Solution {
    public static int lastVal = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
   
    public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
        
        boolean result = true;
        boolean leftResult = true;
        boolean rightResult = true;
        
        if (root.left != null) {
            leftResult = isValidBST(root.left);
        }
        
        if (root.val <= lastVal) {
            result = false;
        } else {
            lastVal = root.val;
        }
        
        
        System.out.println();
        
        if (root.right != null) {
            rightResult = isValidBST(root.right);
        }
       
        
        if (!leftResult || !rightResult) {
            result = false;
        } 
        
        
        return result;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't expect that people know what you mean with Leetcode. I thought you meant 1337<0)3. Btw. don't program for such sites, their test-scripts are often buggy and stupid.

Comment: Your code can only work correct if each test loads your class separately. Probably leetcode runs several tests one after the other, without reloading your code.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is you should run this program on your local development id and verify that it is behaving the same or giving some accurate result. In this way, you will get your answer of **Is there some problem with Leetcode or am I just missing something?**